# Can we control whether Flash passes a referrer or not when it fetches video content?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, flash

I have noticed that in Firefox when playing a mp4/flv file via a swf player, A referrer is not sent from the swf player. However if we switch over to Chrome, a referrer is sent.

With this being said, is there a way in flash (via markup or internal programming) to decide if we want to pass or not pass the referrer?